# comparing two strings sectioned into different parameters in C

Tags: c

I'm fairly new to all of this and I somehow can't seem to find a solution. Although I have no syntax errors, the program doesn't work as its supposed to.

I want the users to input two firmnames [**int read ()**] which get saved under the char arrays x and y. From there I want to compare them both if they are equal or not [**int equal()**]. After that, if they are equal, I want to print out accordingly[**int stringconcatenate()**]

I want **read() ; equal() ; stringconcatenate() to be connected with the main program and work accordingly.

I'm trying to take the entered "firmnames" and then save them under the array name x and y. (which doesn't work as it should).. Am I missing something?

this is what I get if I enter "test" for both firmnames:

```
Please type in Firmname 1:      test
Please type in Firmname 2:      test
Strings are unequal.
 a & ³■a are different.
```

Any tips are very much appreciated.
Btw, I'm not allowed to use strcmp, hence my unorthodox code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int read (){
char x[50]; 
char y[50];

    printf("Please type in Firmname 1:\t");
    scanf("%s", &x);
    printf("Please type in Firmname 2:\t");
    scanf("%s", &y);


}
int Equal (char x[], char y[]){

char *p1,*p2;
int f = 0;

p1=x;
p2=y;

while (*p1!= '\0' || *p2!='\0'){
    if(*p1 != *p2){
        f=1;
        break;
    }
    p1++;
    p2++;
}
if (f==0)
    printf("\nStrings are equal.\n");
else
    printf("Strings are unequal.");

}

int stringconcatenate(char x[], char y[]){ 


char *p1,*p2;

p1=x;
p2=y;


if (*p1==*p2){
    printf ("\n %s is the only one.", x);
    
}
else 
printf ("\n %s & %s are different.", x, y);
return 0;
}

int main(){

char s1[50], s2[50];
    printf("Program Compare\n\n");
    read ();
    Equal (s1, s2);
    stringconcatenate(s1, s2);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: 1. Which input do you provide to your program? 2. What does the program output? 3. What do you want it to output? You can [edit] your question to clarify. See also [mcve].

Comment: Do you want to compare two strings ?

Comment: I want the users to input two firmnames[read ()] which gets saved under the char array x and y. From there I want to compare them both if they are equal or not [equal()]. After that, IF they are equal, I want to print out accordingly[stringconcatenate()]

Comment: @namine07 please [edit] your question and put all relevant information _there_

Comment: Your `read` function reads and throws away input. It also has undefined behavior because it doesn't return a value as its type indicates. Please [turn on your compiler warnings and treat them as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Comment: I now have editted as much as I could.. any help is appreciated.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: It is not undefined behavior in C for a function declared with a non-void return type to return without returning a value (by letting program control flow to its terminating `}`). It is only undefined behavior of an attempt to use the value of the function call is made. This can be used in functions that sometimes return a value and sometimes do not, such as a function that gets or sets a stored configuration value based on whether a parameter requests getting, setting, or some other action.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is your `read` function which is wrong.
In your original code, `x` and `y` are *local* variables which exist only during the execution of the `read` function; afterwards the are discarded and cannot be used any more. Furthermore there is no reason why `x` and `y` would be magically copied to `s1`and `s2`.

This is the corrected version of `read`:

```
int read(char x[50], char y[50]) {  //
  printf("Please type in Firmname 1:\t");
  scanf("%s", x);   // use x and not &x, x is already an address
  printf("Please type in Firmname 2:\t");
  scanf("%s", y);   //
}
```

and call it like this from main:

```
read(s1, s2);
```

There are more problems in your code:

- `Equal` and `read` are `int` function, but they don't return anything, so they should rather be `void` functions.
- Rather than displaying if the strings are equal or not, `Equal` should return e.g. 1 if the strings are equal and 0 if they are not and the display of the result should be done in `main`. This is not a programming error but rather a design error.
- your `strconcatenate` function doesn't even attempt to do a string concatenation. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this code.

Answer (score 1):

*Note, I assume this is an assignment, so I will only include some pointers (no puns intended) so that you can correct the mistakes by yourself.*

Ok, let's address problems function by function.

```
int read (){
    char x[50]; 
    char y[50];

    printf("Please type in Firmname 1:\t");
    scanf("%s", &x);
    printf("Please type in Firmname 2:\t");
    scanf("%s", &y);


}
```

This function simply reads two strings from standard input (stdin from now on) and then *it throws them away.* Neither `x` nor `y` are in some ways returned to the `main` function, that means that, when you call `read` in the main, and I assume you expect `s1` and `s2` to have, respectively, the value of `x` and `y`, `s1` and `s2` *do not* change. What you can do to address this problem is to pass a pointer to `s1` and `s2` to the read function. In fact, in the C language *arrays used in expression have the same value of the pointer to their first element* (for instance, if I use `s1` in an expression, it gets converted to the pointer to the first element of `s1`). That being said, please pass |(the pointers of) `s1` and `s2` to the `read` function and use `scanf` on them. Another problem with this function is that it says that it returns an `int`, but it fact it returns nothing. Please change the function to address this problem.
(There is another problem with the read function that is "what if I input, for instance, the entire GPL license? The program will not be happy and it might crash. Please have a look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)).

The second function I see is this:

```
int Equal (char x[], char y[]){

char *p1,*p2;
int f = 0;

p1=x;
p2=y;

while (*p1!= '\0' || *p2!='\0'){
    if(*p1 != *p2){
        f=1;
        break;
    }
    p1++;
    p2++;
}
if (f==0)
    printf("\nStrings are equal.\n");
else
    printf("Strings are unequal.");

}
```

Please, don't use general purpose functions like this to print to standard output. Make equal return a value (for instance 0 if the strings are equal, 1 otherwise).
The `while` loop condition is wrong: what you're saying is that "if `*p1` is not `'\0'` OR `*p2` is not `'\0'`, then go forward with the loop. If one is `'\0'` but the other is not, the loop will go forward.

I can't figure out what you want to achieve with the `stringconcatenate` function. Please explain.